# Generating and applying random top and left

Tags: jquery, random

I am working on creating an image gallery. When a user clicks on an image, I am trying to shuffle the other images in a given section by applying random top and left values. Most of this is working, except, when I click on the photo, the same random top and left values are applied to all of the photos in that section. I would like to apply a different random top and left value to the other photos in the section. Here is my code for generating and applying the values, thus far:

```
    //Move all the photos in the section
    function movePhotos() {
        var randomTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1;
        var randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1;
        var photos = $(this).parent().find('.photo');

        photos.animate({ 'left': randomLeft, 'top': randomTop, }, 2000);
        $(this).stop().animate({ 'top': '0px', 'left': '100px' }).css({'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': '100000'});   
    };

        $('.full-size, .photo').click(movePhotos);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the jQuery [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function:

```
    //Move all the photos in the section
function movePhotos() {

    var photos = $(this).parent().find('.photo');

    photos.each(function(i,E){ 
        var randomTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1;
        var randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1;
        $(E).animate({ 'left': randomLeft, 'top': randomTop, }, 2000);

    });   
    $(this).stop().animate({ 'top': '0px', 'left': '100px' }).css({'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': '100000'});
};
```

Comment: Beautiful. This did the trick. I knew/hoped I wasn't far off and I had thought about the .each() function. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Each photo needs to generate a random number, so you need to loop through them. jQuery lets you do that with `each()`

```
//Move all the photos in the section
function movePhotos() {
    $(this).parent().find('.photo').each(function(){
        var randomTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1;
        var randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1;
        $(this).animate({ 'left': randomLeft, 'top': randomTop, }, 2000);

    });

    $(this).stop().animate({ 'top': '0px', 'left': '100px' }).css({'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': '100000'});   
};

$('.full-size, .photo').click(movePhotos);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sitting at  my dev pc at the moment so I can't verify this is correct.  However, it looks like you need an .each() iterator for your animate method.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your randomizer a function to ensure a new value is generated each time your code loops :

```
  function randomTop() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1;
  }

  function randomLeft() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1;
  }

function movePhotos() {

        var photos = $(this).parent().find('.photo');
        photos.animate({ 'left': randomLeft(), 'top': randomTop(), }, 2000);
        $(this).stop().animate({ 'top': '0px', 'left': '100px' }).css({'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': '100000'});   
    };
```